Azure OpenAI and Azure AI Search Service URL returns 404 Resource not found
I am trying to call the following URL in Azure OpenAI, which connects Azure OpenAI with Azure AI Search Service:
api_base/openai/deployments/gpt-4o-eu2/extensions/chat/completions?api-version=2024-02-15-preview

However, I am getting the following error:
{"error":{"code":"404","message": "Resource not found"}}

When I use this URL, which is used to connect with just the Azure OpenAI API, it works properly:
api_base/openai/deployments/gpt-4o-eu2/extensions/completions?api-version=2024-02-15-preview

I am testing these URLs in Postman and passing all the required parameters and api_key correctly.
What could be the reason for the 404 error with the first URL?

I believe the reason you are getting this error is because you are calling a chat completion endpoint (chat/completions) with GPT-4o model which it does not support. Only completion endpoints are supported in GPT-4o. Please see this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/reference#chat-completions.
If you need to use chat completion endpoint, you will need to use either GPT-4 or GPT-35-Turbo models as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/reference#chat-completions.
